# Get file size from "Content-Length" value from a file in python 3.2

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, urllib

I want to get the `Content-Length` value from the meta variable. I need to get the size of the file that I want to download. But the last line returns an error, `HTTPMessage` object has no attribute `getheaders`.

```
import urllib.request
import http.client

#----HTTP HANDLING PART----
 url = "http://client.akamai.com/install/test-objects/10MB.bin"

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
d = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')

#----GET FILE SIZE----
meta = d.info()

print ("Download Details", meta)
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are using Python 3, and have read some code / documentation for Python 2.x. It is poorly documented, but there is no `getheaders` method in Python 3, but only a `get_all` method.

See [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue4773).

Comment: For the benefit of people from Google, it seems you can now do `file_size = int(d.getheader('Content-Length'))` in Python 3 (tested in 3.4.1). `d.getheaders()` also seems to have been added.

Comment: @freshtop: Both `d.getheader()` and `d.getheaders()` work even on Python 3.2. Note: OP uses `d.info()` instead of `d` here. `d.info().getheader()` and `d.info().getheaders()` is Python 2 code. To support both Python 2 and 3, [`d.headers['Content-Length']` could be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576222).

Answer (score 7):

for `Content-Length`:

```
file_size = int(d.getheader('Content-Length'))
```

Comment: I think they are looking for a python3 solution, (at least I am and this is the top google hit)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: `d.getheader()` works on Python 3 only. The question has python-3.x tag and therefore Python 3 only solution is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Change final line to:

```
file_size = int(meta.get_all("Content-Length")[0])
```

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

url = "http://client.akamai.com/install/test-objects/10MB.bin"
resp = requests.get(url)

print resp.headers['content-length']
# '10485760'
```

For Python 3, use:

```
print(resp.headers['content-length'])
```

instead.

Comment: +1, If you only expect one header, go with the item operator. However, I fear there is no `headers` attribute in Python3, so it should probably be `resp.get("Content-Length")` or maybe `resp["Content-Length"]` (didn't try this)

Comment: seems to be no requests libraries in python 3.2...think i should switch versions...which version you guys using ?

Comment: @scandalous `Requests` recently added 3.3 support. I am running 2.7.3.

Comment: @Krumelur That wasn't an issue, as `resp` is a `Requests` response dict. There's one thing I need to change though.. it should be `print(resp.headers)` instead for Python3.

Comment: @scandalous You are welcome! I forgot to change `print` statement to python3's format in the original answer.

Comment: @KayZhu, yes of course. Overlooked that you had removed the `info()` call :)

Comment: @Krumelur ah ok, though I didn't really remove anything in my post edit. There was never a `info()` call, I suppose you meant you mislooked? :)

Answer (score 2):

`response.headers['Content-Length']` works on both Python 2 and 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import closing

try:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError: # Python 3
    from urllib.request import urlopen


with closing(urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/q/12996274')) as response:
    print("File size: " + response.headers['Content-Length'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a header is repeated. You only get the first one when using the `headers` attribute. The *only* reliable way is to use `info().get_all()`. In Python2 `info().get()` would concatenate all duplicate headers but this fragile behavior has been removed for Py3. Unfortunately `get_all()` hasn't been backported to Py2 so we are stuck having to wrestle with this poorly documented library for more years to come.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau: 1- [duplicate Content-Length headers with different values are not supported in http](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#page-31) 2- `info()` is implemented as `return self.headers`.

Comment: From [RFC-6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-3): "Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field". It is not at all unusual to receive duplicate headers. Python's libraries need to support this behavior properly.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau: [Set-Cookie is a well-known exception -- you should not use it as an example for other http headers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#page-24). rfc7230 specifies the behavior for the Content-Length header explicitly (read the link from my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request

link = "<url here>"

f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
meta = f.info()
print (meta.get("Content-length"))
f.close()
```

Works with python 3.x