# Safely read post body in http request handler?

Tags: python, http, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

How do you safely read the post body of an HTTP POST request in a HTTP Request Handler in Python 3.+

I keep seeing solutions like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888504/python-basehttprequesthandler-read-raw-post).

That solution only works if the request includes the `content-length` header and that header is accurate.  Many times `content-length` gets excluded and is unreliable, any solution based on that is just frail.  How do you return data from the `rfile` buffer without causing it hang by trying to read non existent bytes?